# Javascript how to pass data between two <script> within <head>

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to use data that was calculated in one script in another script?

For example within head this script gets a customer email

**Edit:** Added var customer_email; but getting undefined when using customer_email outside of loadSuccess() function.

```
<script>
      var customer_email;

      async function loadSuccess() {   

      const response = await fetch('/.netlify/functions/success', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      }).then((res) => res.json())
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));;

      customer_email = response.session.customer_details.email;
      console.log(customer_email);
      }
      loadSuccess(); 
      console.log(customer_email); 
    } 
</script>

<script>
     console.log(customer_email); 
</script>
```

Now in a different  also within , how can customer_email be used?

In this example, only the 1st console.log(customer_email) within loadSuccess() prints the email.  The other 2 print undefined.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make customer_email a global variable

```
<script>
  var customer_email;
  async function loadSuccess() {   

  const response = await fetch('/.netlify/functions/success', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  }).then((res) => res.json())
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));;

  customer_email = response.session.customer_details.email;
  }
  loadSuccess();  
} 
</script>
```

Comment: After adding var customer_email, console.log(customer_email) is still showing as undefined. Is it because it is running console.log(customer_email) before loadSuccess() finishes?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to assign your value to a global variable, such as window._customer_Email.

```
window._customer_Email = response.session.customer_details.email;
```

Then you can access this in the same way

```
console.log(window._customer_Email)
```

Note that global variables are something recommended against because they cannot be garbage collected easily and also pollute the global state (risking conflicts)